# I upgrade from Debian 9 to 10 and middle-click stops working

Tags: debian, xorg, mouse, wayland, mouse-gestures

Recently I upgrade Debian on my laptop from Stretch to Buster. I noticed some problems (some apps stopped working, there was no drag 'n drop, Nvidia 3D card was not functional, etc), so I searched the Internet and realized it was related to Wayland. Since then, I've run Gnome on Xorg.

Everything looks fine now, except the middle-click. Clicking on mouse wheel doesn't work anymore.

I searched the Internet again and all answers I found say about checking `org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/middle-button-enabled` in `dconf-editor` or edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` directly.

Unfortunately, in my `dconf-editor` there's no `middle-button-enabled` in `org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/`
And also there's no `xorg.conf` at `/etc/X11/`

What else can I do to re-enable/reactivate middle-click?

P.S.: Touchpad seems to be working fine (clicking on both buttons acts as a middle-click on most app, triple touch on touchpad as well).

---

[edit¹]
I unplugged and plugged mouse usb again and then `dmesg` showed:

```
vinicius@Menbung:~$ sudo dmesg
[ 1011.128101] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 1020.383018] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 1020.537022] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52f, bcdDevice=30.00
[ 1020.537024] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1020.537025] usb 1-2: Product: USB Receiver
[ 1020.537026] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[ 1020.540971] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:046D:C52F.0007/input/input28
[ 1020.541080] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0007: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[ 1020.542265] input: Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:046D:C52F.0008/input/input29
[ 1020.599128] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52F.0008: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
```

---

[edit²]
I thought I had solved the issue...

At first, I searched Internet to find my xorg.conf, which I think wayland hid. I didn't find it, but I found something I thought was somewhat equivalent (based on [xorg.conf manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/xserver-xorg-core/xorg.conf.5.en.html)): `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`. 
Then I added to the end of this file (based on [this thread](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=103804) and [this FAQ](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/faqs.html#how-do-i-configure-my-device-on-wayland)):

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "middle button emulation class"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    Option "Emulate3Buttons" "on"
EndSection
```

At first apparently it didn't work.

So I decided to install `xinput` package from debian repositories.

Found my mouse on `$ xinput list`, then listed its properties `$ xinput list-props 10` (10 is my device id) and this line caught my attention:

```
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (297):   0
```

I simply changed 0 to 1:

```
$ xinput set-prop 10 "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled" 1
```

Again, at first apparently it didn't work. Then I try it with `sudo`. No effect. But I realized something happened, the middle-click sometimes worked sometimes not. Then I found this: "[Make sure "Middle Mouse Button Emulation" is disabled or you'll get 50ms left-click latency](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/7xd9ix/psa_in_linux_make_sure_middle_mouse_button/)".

I changed back `libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (297)` to 0.

The latency was gone.

But after a while, middle-click simply stops working, until I change `libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (297)` to 1 (and middle-click works with latency) and again to 0 (when latency stops)... after a while middle-click stops working again.

Comment: Any errors in `dmesg` when you try to middle click?

Comment: @ChuckHorowitz I edited the question to show what dmseg says about the mouse. No error. I don't know if I use dmseg right, mouse clicks don't change dmseg info.